# Cannot copy files on another user account on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, copy-paste

[image: ![Cannot drag and copy/ copy and paste]
We have 3 users on our Windows 11 PC.

```
Main account (Administrator)
Second account (Administrator)
Third account (Standard user)
```

The main account is working just fine, but the second and third cannot copy any files, in any directory. When I'm trying to paste files within the user account, the screen suddenly refreshes, and nothing happens.

I already tried the following commands:

```
chkdsk /f
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
sfc /scannow
cmd /c"echo off|clip
```

I also already tried restarting rdpclip.exe and disabling controlled folder access.

Comment: Have you created the users in a non-standard way?

Comment: Or you have modified the permissions of the other users.

Comment: @harrymc no. Since I used the PC, I only created user via User Accounts in the Settings. I did not mess with the permissions

Answer (score 0):

> When I'm trying to paste files within the user account, the screen
> suddenly refreshes, and nothing happens.

The different user accounts are secured from each other. So you have a permission situation and that is entirely normal.

You can use the Public Folder area within USERS to interchange files between users and that will work.

That is to say, Public folders can be used as a common storage area for multiple users.  I have tested this with multiple users on Windows 11 Pro .  Files in Public are available to ALL users.

Use File Explorer to see Public as a folder area underneath USERS.

You may need to use Explorer Options to see hidden files.

But overall what you see is entirely normal.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear. I wasn't trying to transfer files to another user. For example, the second user, which is an administrator logs on to his own user account. If he tries to copy or paste any files within his library (not to other user's folder), the error above occurs. Assume there is a file name asdf.xlsx on the Desktop, if I tried to duplicate that file, or transfer the file to a subfolder within the Desktop, the error appears.

Comment: Use the Public folder area to transfer the files. It is an extra step but it should prevent the area. That is what it was designed for.

Comment: But I wasn't trying to transfer files between users. I was trying to transfer file within the user account. Anyway, I just tried saving to Public folder but the same error occurs.

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with your OS because Public Folders do work.

Comment: When I use the first user account to copy to Public Folders, it works tho. I tried to delete and create a new user account but the problem persists. This is annoying, it's like Windows 11 is telling me that I should only have 1 user account.

Comment: I am not certain what is going on with your machine. I just took a Windows 11 Pro machine with multiple users, went to user A, put a file in Public (Documents). Then I restart in main User and the file was there in Public (Documents). It is not a matter of transferring files - it is just using Public as a common storage area for multiple users. In a normally set up Windows 11 machine this works.

Comment: I tested the concepts and added the testing to my answer. Works for all users.